# macOS system appearance resource files (.car) location for accent colors

Tags: macos, catalina, color

I was wondering where the resource files for the accent colors are located? The normal aqua, dark aqua, accessibility, … appearance files are all located at this location: `/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemAppearance.bundle/Contents/Resources`

Though I can't find the files for the accent colors. Does someone know how this works? Maybe they re-color the blue assets in the code during runtime?